# What is the Difference Between First and Second Order Quantum Phase Transitions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

I have been reading some books (ex: *Quantum Phase Transitions* by Subir Sachdev) and online materials ([this](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/aad5f9) and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0610624)) to understand the similarities and differences between quantum first and second order transitions. I have learned that second order quantum phase transitions involve infinite correlation length, algebraic decay of correlation function, universality class and conformal field theory, spontaneous symmetry breaking, gapless energy spectrum, and quantum fluctuations. However, I did not clearly understand what first order quantum phase transitions. **Out of the six characteristics of second order quantum phase transitions already mentioned, which of these exist during a quantum first order phase transition? Are their additional things that exist during a first order quantum phase transition?**

Comment: Look up the difference between first and second order phase transitions. "Quantum" here does not alter them.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thank you very much.